# IO exception client/server socket

Tags: android, client-server, android-wireless

I am writing a client/server program to send data over my own local internet wireless network.
In the client side, I wrote this snippet

```
private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 63400
    try {
        // provide a client side TCP socket

        Socket s = new Socket("192.168.1.102", TCP_SERVER_PORT);
            ...
```

It throws an IOException. I add the INTERNET permission though.
I am joining the local DSL internet wifi network. Is it because of the router?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is port 63400 on 192.168.1.102 open?

try

```
telnet 192.168.1.102 63400
```

if it returns anything then the port is open, and the problem is somewhere else. If it says "name or service unknown" then there is no one listening @ 192.168.1.102:63400

EDIT:
just noticed the android tag. Don't know if u have shell/telnet on android, but you can use this method from PC both windows and linux shell

Comment: can u scan a printer(wifi) if u know its ip adress. If yes then plz help me. I m a newbie .

Comment: with this method you can test is there some program listening on the given port at the given IP address. you should ask a question. see how [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)